# How can I make Ubuntu 16.04 use the AMDGPU driver for my RX560 GPU?

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl, amdgpu

I have recently installed an AMD RX 560 GPU card in my machine. It appears to work OK - the machine boots successfully and I'm typing this message on it. However, for some reason the `amdgpu` driver is not claiming the card. (And yes, the monitor is plugged into the discrete card's HDMI port, not the built-in VGA port.)

`lsmod` immediately after boot reveals that the `amdgpu` module is loaded. However, `lshw -c video` reports the card as UNCLAIMED (while reporting other details, such as the chipset, correctly). Also, `glxinfo` reports the renderer as `llvmpipe`, which I believe is not what I should expect if the machine is using hardware video acceleration.

The machine's on-board video is Nvidia, so there's no chance I am confusing my new AMD card with the on-board one.

My question is simply, why might the `amdgpu` driver behave in this way, and how can I make it act as the driver for my video card? Or am I confused and things are actually acting as they are supposed to? (In which case, how do I enable hardware acceleration for OpenGL?)

Output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  2
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
kvm_amd                65536  0
snd_hda_core           77824  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
kvm                   548864  1 kvm_amd
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
input_leds             16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
edac_mce_amd           24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
k10temp                16384  0
edac_core              53248  0
shpchp                 36864  0
asus_atk0110           20480  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
i2c_nforce2            16384  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
mac_hid                16384  0
amdkfd                131072  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
amdgpu                991232  0
ttm                    98304  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 amdgpu
drm                   364544  3 ttm,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  1
hid                   122880  5 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
pata_acpi              16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
firewire_ohci          40960  0
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
psmouse               131072  0
ahci                   36864  2
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
forcedeth              69632  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
pata_amd               20480  0
video                  40960  0
wmi                    20480  1 mxm_wmi
fjes                   28672  0
```

Output of `lshw -c video` (the built-in Nvidia chip does not appear, I guess having a discrete card installed in and/or monitor attached to the discrete card disables it at the hardware level, or something):

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:efe00000-efffffff ioport:dc00(size=256) memory:fdc80000-fdcbffff memory:fdcc0000-fdcdffff
```

Output of `glxinfo` (snipped modes etc for brevity):

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 128 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 17.2.8
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 7982MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated.) Sort-of solved. I upgraded my Ubuntu install to 17.10, rebooted, and now have an accelerated graphics pipeline. So this doesn't answer the specific question of how to make amdgpu work on 16.04, but from the volume of other questions about that topic it seems like the answer is, "Don't bother. Just upgrade."

Update: after a couple of reboots of 17.10, with no changes to the video configuration, I'm back to square -1. The 4.13 kernel is now booting to a black screen and the machine is totally unresponsive - `Ctrl-Alt-Fn` doesn't take me to a text login session. If I boot the older 4.4 kernel the machine boots successfully, but once again, no hardware acceleration :-(

Update 2: A 4.16 kernel built from source seems to be able to consistently boot with AMDGPU support enabled and working for the RX 560.